# Django Weasyprint bootstrap styling lost

Tags: django, weasyprint

I have a HTML template in Django that I am creating a PDF with using WeasyPrint. However, my bootstrap styling is lost when the PDF is created:

```
html_string = render_to_string('index.html', {'data' : data, 'total' : total_price, 'cash' : cash_price, 'paid' : paid, 'hm_fees' : hm_fees, 'invoice_number' : invoice_number, 'total_sales' :total_sales})
html = HTML(string=html_string)
result = html.write_pdf()

response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf;')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=invoice.pdf'
response['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary'
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as output:
    output.write(result)
    output.flush()
    output.seek(0)
    response.write(output.read())

return response
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We need to add the CSS from WeasyPrint into Django views:

```
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
```

Also need to reference the bootstrap file in this manner:

```
result = html.write_pdf(stylesheets=[CSS('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',)])
```